# Google Script - Google Sheets + Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace

I'm trying to do the following thing:
When updating column A in a specific spreadsheet my code on script. google. com should trigger and create a headline (ideally headline 3) in a specific google doc. But I'm encountering issues.

(Ideally it should also create a dropdown menu that's synced to the one in the same row in column b in my sheet meaning if I select "completed" in front of "name 1" it should set the dropdown for that row in sheet to the same. ANyway that's a problem for later, the first part isn't even working)

My executions shows me that it triggers, but "Type Editor" fails, so the action step.

Trigger is set to "on edit" "from spreadsheet" (wouldn't let me choose a particular one).

The error message I get when trying to run it manually or debugging it is
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit  @ Code.gs:10"

Tried a few chatgpt fixes etc already. Any ideas?

My code is the following:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Define your Google Doc and Google Sheet IDs
  var docId = "1PYB60CS4wTI0o1u_r4YUgnOQlBsxo6hj2Dj-aWz93hY";
  var sheetName = "Test Auto"; // Replace with the name of your target sheet

  // Log that the onEdit function is triggered
  Logger.log("onEdit function triggered");

  // Get the active range
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();

  // Log information about the edit event
  Logger.log("Edit event in sheet: " + sheet.getName());
  Logger.log("Edited column: " + range.getColumn());
  Logger.log("Edited value: " + e.value);

  // Check if the edited range is on the desired sheet and has a new value in column A
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetName && range.getColumn() === 1 && e.value) {
    var name = e.value;
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    var body = doc.getBody();

    // Log that the script is entering this block
    Logger.log("Creating heading for: " + name);

    // Create a new heading 3 with the name from the sheet
    var heading = body.appendParagraph(name).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);

    // Add a dropdown to the heading in the Google Doc
    var listItem = heading.appendListItem("not started");
    listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    listItem.setListId(DocumentApp.ListItemType.BULLETED);
    listItem = heading.appendListItem("needs visual");
    listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    listItem.setListId(DocumentApp.ListItemType.BULLETED);
    listItem = heading.appendListItem("completed");
    listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    listItem.setListId(DocumentApp.ListItemType.BULLETED);

    // Log that the heading is created
    Logger.log("Heading created for: " + name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you will need to create an installable onEdit trigger. !!Don't name it onEdit.  I changed the name of my function to onMyEdit(e); and I reduced some of your over head by utilizing the event object better.  But I haven't tested it.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("onEdit Entry");
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() === "Test Auto" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById("1PYB60CS4wTI0o1u_r4YUgnOQlBsxo6hj2Dj-aWz93hY");
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var heading = body.appendParagraph(e.value).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
    var listItem = heading.appendListItem("not started");
    listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    listItem.setListId(DocumentApp.ListItemType.BULLETED);
    listItem = heading.appendListItem("needs visual");
    listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    listItem.setListId(DocumentApp.ListItemType.BULLETED);
    listItem = heading.appendListItem("completed");
    listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    listItem.setListId(DocumentApp.ListItemType.BULLETED);
  }
}
```

> The first thing you will want to do is to create an installable onEdit trigger

Comment: Let me know how it goes after you create the new trigger

Answer (score 0):

Use this `testOnEdit` function to manually test the functionality:

```py
function testOnEdit() {
    var mockEvent = {
        range: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test Auto").getRange("A2"),
        value: "Sample Name"
    };
    onEdit(mockEvent);
}
```

Also, make sure you've set up triggers correctly in the Apps Script dashboard. Ensure you have the correct sheet specified and the correct permissions granted.